# How to combine three animations as the following example?

Tags: pstricks

EX1:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}%
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,-1,-2,...,-180}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
\pnodes(3,3){A}(1,-1){B}(7,-1){C}
\psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
\pstMiddleAB[PosAngle=135]{A}{B}{M}
\pstMiddleAB{A}{C}{N}
\pstMiddleAB{M}{N}{I}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=pstslash]{A}{M}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHash]{A}{N}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashh]{M}{N}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{N}{M}{A}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{A}{N}{M}{}
\pspolygon(A)(M)(N)
\pstRotation[RotAngle=\i]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]%%%%<<--
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n}{m}{a}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a)(m)(n)
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EX2:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}%
\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {0,1,2,...,180}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
\pnodes(3,3){A}(1,-1){B}(7,-1){C}
\psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
\pstMiddleAB[PosAngle=135]{A}{B}{M}
\pstMiddleAB{A}{C}{N}
\pstMiddleAB{M}{N}{I}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=-180]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]%%%%<<--
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n}{m}{a}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a)(m)(n)

\pstMiddleAB{a}{n}{I1}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=\i]{I1}{a,m,n}[a1,m1,n1]%%%%<<--
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=pstslash]{a1}{m1}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashhh]{n1}{m1}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n1}{m1}{a1}{}
%\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a1)(m1)(n1)
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EX3:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}%
\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {0,-1,-2,...,-180}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
\pnodes(3,3){A}(1,-1){B}(7,-1){C}
\psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
\pstMiddleAB[PosAngle=135]{A}{B}{M}
\pstMiddleAB{A}{C}{N}
\pstMiddleAB{M}{N}{I}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=-180]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]%%%%<<--
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n}{m}{a}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a)(m)(n)

\pstMiddleAB{a}{m}{I2}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=\i]{I2}{a,m,n}[a2,m2,n2]%%%%<<--
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashh]{a2}{m2}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashhh]{n2}{m2}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a2}{n2}{m2}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a2)(m2)(n2)
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question:

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XnSWToM3dE).

Finally,

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}%
\begin{document}
 %%
\def\figone{%
\pnodes(3,3){A}(1,-1){B}(7,-1){C}
\psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
\pstMiddleAB[PosAngle=135]{A}{B}{M}
\pstMiddleAB{A}{C}{N}
\pstMiddleAB{M}{N}{I}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=pstslash]{A}{M}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashh]{A}{N}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashhh]{M}{N}
\psset{fillstyle=solid}
\pstMarkAngle[fillcolor=green]{N}{M}{A}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillcolor=blue]{A}{N}{M}{}
\pspolygon[fillcolor=green,opacity=.3](A)(M)(N)}%
\def\figonee#1{%
\pstRotation[RotAngle=#1]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]
\psset{fillstyle=solid}
\pstMarkAngle[fillcolor=green]{n}{m}{a}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red,fillcolor=green,opacity=.3](a)(m)(n)}%
\def\figtwo#1{%
\pstMiddleAB{a}{n}{I1}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=#1]{I1}{a,m,n}[a1,m1,n1]
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=pstslash]{a1}{m1}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashhh]{n1}{m1}
\psset{fillstyle=solid}
\pstMarkAngle[fillcolor=green]{n1}{m1}{a1}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red,fillcolor=green,opacity=.3](a1)(m1)(n1)}%
%%
\multido{\i=0+-3}{61}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
\figone
\figonee{\i}
\end{pspicture}%
 }
\multido{\i=0+3}{61}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
\figone
\figonee{-180}
\figtwo{\i}
\end{pspicture}%
}
\multido{\i=0+-3}{61}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
\figone
\figonee{-180}
\figtwo{180}
\pstMiddleAB{a}{m}{I2}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=\i]{I2}{a,m,n}[a2,m2,n2]
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashh]{a2}{n2}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashhh]{n2}{m2}
\psset{fillstyle=solid}
\pstMarkAngle[fillcolor=blue]{a2}{n2}{m2}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red,fillcolor=green,opacity=.3](a2)(m2)(n2)
\end{pspicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you should mark the current rotation point (fix point)

Comment: @Herbert I do not understand what you say, I don't see problem as the given video. Can you give me a sample? ...

Comment: only for your first rotation the rotation point is marked by ///. The // is missing for the following triangles, or least a dot.

Comment: @Herbert Done, I think so ...

Comment: yes, looks good now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}%

\def\first#1{%
\pnodes(3,3){A}(1,-1){B}(7,-1){C}
\psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
\pstMiddleAB[PosAngle=135]{A}{B}{M}
\pstMiddleAB{A}{C}{N}
\pstMiddleAB{M}{N}{I}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=pstslash]{A}{M}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHash]{A}{N}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashh]{M}{N}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{N}{M}{A}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{A}{N}{M}{}
\pspolygon(A)(M)(N)
\pstRotation[RotAngle=#1]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]%%%%<<--
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n}{m}{a}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a)(m)(n)}

\def\second#1{%
\pnodes(3,3){A}(1,-1){B}(7,-1){C}
\psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
\pstMiddleAB[PosAngle=135]{A}{B}{M}
\pstMiddleAB{A}{C}{N}
\pstMiddleAB{M}{N}{I}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=-180]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]%%%%<<--
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n}{m}{a}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a)(m)(n)    
\pstMiddleAB{a}{n}{I1}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=#1]{I1}{a,m,n}[a1,m1,n1]%%%%<<--
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=pstslash]{a1}{m1}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashhh]{n1}{m1}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n1}{m1}{a1}{}
%\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a1)(m1)(n1)}


\def\third#1{
\pnodes(3,3){A}(1,-1){B}(7,-1){C}
\psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
\pstMiddleAB[PosAngle=135]{A}{B}{M}
\pstMiddleAB{A}{C}{N}
\pstMiddleAB{M}{N}{I}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=-180]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]%%%%<<--
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n}{m}{a}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a)(m)(n)

\pstMiddleAB{a}{m}{I2}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=#1]{I2}{a,m,n}[a2,m2,n2]%%%%<<--
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashh]{a2}{m2}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashhh]{n2}{m2}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a2}{n2}{m2}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a2)(m2)(n2)}

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,-10,...,-180}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
\first{\i}
\end{pspicture}}
\foreach \i in {0,-10,...,-180}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
\first{0}
\second{\i}
\end{pspicture}}
\foreach \i in {0,-10,...,-180}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
\first{0}
\second{-180}
\third{\i}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The above code has many redundancies that we can refactor but I left it as it is right now.

Comment: @chishimutoji: Your next job is to compare `\first`, `\second`, and `\third` and refactor them to remove the unnecessary redundancies. DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself because redundancies don't reflect perfectionism. :-)

Answer (score 4):

`ex2` also needs the last image (180°) from `ex1` and `ex3` also needs the last images from `ex1` *and*  `ex2`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}%
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+3}{60}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
\pnodes(3,3){A}(1,-1){B}(7,-1){C}
\psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
\pstMiddleAB[PosAngle=135]{A}{B}{M}
\pstMiddleAB{A}{C}{N}
\pstMiddleAB{M}{N}{I}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=pstslash]{A}{M}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHash]{A}{N}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashh]{M}{N}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{N}{M}{A}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{A}{N}{M}{}
\pspolygon(A)(M)(N)
\pstRotation[RotAngle=\i]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]%%%%<<--
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n}{m}{a}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a)(m)(n)
\end{pspicture}%
}
\multido{\i=0+3}{60}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
\pnodes(3,3){A}(1,-1){B}(7,-1){C}
\psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
\pstMiddleAB[PosAngle=135]{A}{B}{M}
\pstMiddleAB{A}{C}{N}
\pstMiddleAB{M}{N}{I}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=pstslash]{A}{M}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHash]{A}{N}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashh]{M}{N}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{N}{M}{A}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{A}{N}{M}{}
\pspolygon(A)(M)(N)
\pstRotation[RotAngle=180]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]%%%%<<--
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n}{m}{a}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a)(m)(n)
% ------------------ end ex1 --------------------------
\pstRotation[RotAngle=-180]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]%%%%<<--
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n}{m}{a}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a)(m)(n)
\pstMiddleAB{a}{n}{I1}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=\i]{I1}{a,m,n}[a1,m1,n1]%%%%<<--
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=pstslash]{a1}{m1}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashhh]{n1}{m1}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n1}{m1}{a1}{}
%\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a1)(m1)(n1)
\end{pspicture}%
}
\multido{\i=0+3}{61}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
\pnodes(3,3){A}(1,-1){B}(7,-1){C}
\psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
\pstMiddleAB[PosAngle=135]{A}{B}{M}
\pstMiddleAB{A}{C}{N}
\pstMiddleAB{M}{N}{I}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=pstslash]{A}{M}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHash]{A}{N}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashh]{M}{N}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{N}{M}{A}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{A}{N}{M}{}
\pspolygon(A)(M)(N)
\pstRotation[RotAngle=180]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]%%%%<<--
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n}{m}{a}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a)(m)(n)
% ------------------ end ex1 --------------------------
\pstRotation[RotAngle=-180]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]%%%%<<--
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n}{m}{a}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a)(m)(n)
\pstMiddleAB{a}{n}{I1}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=180]{I1}{a,m,n}[a1,m1,n1]%%%%<<--
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=pstslash]{a1}{m1}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashhh]{n1}{m1}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n1}{m1}{a1}{}
%\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a1)(m1)(n1)
% ------------------ end ex2 --------------------------
\pstRotation[RotAngle=-180]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]%%%%<<--
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{n}{m}{a}{}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a}{n}{m}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a)(m)(n)
\pstMiddleAB{a}{m}{I2}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=\i]{I2}{a,m,n}[a2,m2,n2]%%%%<<--
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashh]{a2}{m2}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashhh]{n2}{m2}
\pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{a2}{n2}{m2}{}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](a2)(m2)(n2)
\end{pspicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

There are a lot of duplicate commands which can be deleted. I leave it to you!

Comment: Animation is too slow so it takes much time to see the whole diagram.

Comment: go into the kitchen, get a cup of coffee and then relax while viewing the animation ...

Comment: Yes, I see. I will try it.

Comment: Now the animation is faster enough so I don't need to drink coffee.